# Bug in Cocoa document-based app with the window's document icon popup menu

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nsdocument

I have a document-based app that supports Versions and Autosave. When you click the proxy icon, a popup menu appears like in any other document app, too:

[image: cocoduino menu]

You notice this weird `NSMenuItem` item? It's not supposed to look like that. In Quartz Composer for example it looks like this:

[image]

I don't know why this happens, as I'm not doing anything with the window title or icon. There isn't even an API to customize this popup menu.
It would be great if somebody could help me to get this fixed or at least an idea of what could be the cause of this behavior.

Kind regards,
Fabian

Comment: I guess you know the difference between locked and unlocked documents. In your case, your apps' document is not locked, QC's is locked. Maybe this can help how to create documents in locked status http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/308521-locking-an-nsdocument.html

Comment: It happens for locked documents, too. Either way, showing "NSMenuItem" as a title is clearly a bug and not desired behavior. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: hope you filed the bug Fabian

Comment: The problem is that it's not reproducible when starting a new project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a blog post with the solution. This worked for me:
[Versions, validateMenuItem: and NSMenuItem](http://www.malcolmhardie.com/weblogs/angus/2011/12/05/versions-validatemenuitem-and-nsmenuitem/)